# Wait for all tasks in a celery group to finish or error out

Tags: celery

I have a group of celery tasks that I want to run in parallel, and then wait for them all to finish. I am currently using:

```
group(task_list).apply_async().get()
```

(see my other question for more detail: [Wait for all tasks in a celery group to finish or error out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64310225/wait-for-all-tasks-in-a-celery-group-to-finish-or-error-out))
When all of my tasks run without exceptions, this works perfectly. However, if any of the tasks throw an exception, it immediately returns.

I can add a try/except around every task and have it return a custom error object, but then it shows up in the flower dashboard as 'succeeded'.

Is it possible to wait for all errors AND exceptions to finish?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, as some time has gone by, have you solved it anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a chord, not a group. From the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords):

> A chord is a task that only executes after all of the tasks in a
> group have finished executing.

```
result = chord(task_list)(handle_results)
```

> The task id returned by chord() is the id of the callback, so you can wait for it to complete and get the final return value

```
result.get()
```

> So what happens if one of the tasks raises an exception?
> The chord callback result will transition to the failure state, and the error is set to the ChordError exception

```
print(result.traceback)
```

Comment: It seems like this has the same issue as .get(), where I cant get any of the task results if one of them throws an exception?